# Fragment not retaining data

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using some fragments in a tablayout, these fragments hold line charts, displaying data. However when I scroll a fragment or two away and come back the charts are empty, almost like the view was recreated.

Fragments are still very new to me so at this point i thought the fragment would pause and then resume, saving the view state.

I've found a method called setRetainInstance() which I've set to true, like such...

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRetainInstance(true);
    }
```

However the data is still getting lost, am I missing a step ?

Thanks for any tips/ advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and many different attempts I have settled on using ViewModels, this with LiveData has solved not only the fragment retaining data problem I had but rotating the device too.

More info can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Answer (score 0):

`setRetainInstance` is for retaining instance during the configuration change, It will not store your data. For data you need to implement saving data in `onSaveInstanceState` method and reloading data in `onActivityCreated` method.

Comment: Is that in the parent activity or the child fragment that I call this ?

Comment: both in activity and fragment. check this link https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/fragment-state-saving-best-practices/en